# Getting the identity token (id_token) within redirect URI (MVC Controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, claims-based-identity, okta

I'm hoping this is mostly agnostic from Okta (the service we are using for social logins), but I'm having a hard time finding documentation. I'm using .NET Core 2.0+ and my Startup.cs looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => 
    {
        //Configuration pulled from appsettings.json by default:
        options.ClientId = Configuration["okta:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["okta:ClientSecret"];
        options.Authority = Configuration["okta:Issuer"];
        options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
    });
```

A login form within the site allows you to click 'Login to Facebook' and the process of authenticating via the identity provider takes place. When it is confirmed, it punts back to my defined redirect 'Home/Secure'. When the redirect returns, the id_token is in the URL as an anchor:

```
https://localhost:5001/Home/Secure#id_token=XXXXXXX
```

There is also an authorize call that I can see happen that receives a response with the id_token in it as well via the Chrome developer tools console. I'm not as familiar with .NET Core, so I'm having a hard time understanding how I can grab this id_token.

The Request doesn't seem to have the id_token in the Query or QueryString parameters, so I'm not seeing where I can grab it.

Comment: The stuff after the `#` is called the "fragment" of the URI. It is purely client-side, and not available to the server at all. There should be another way to access the token. Perhaps, you're using the wrong flow with the third-party provider. In other words, it seems this particular flow is meant for a JS client.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Okay, so that makes a bit more sense. There is another flow where I can grab it via JS and push it somewhere else. Maybe that's my answer. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You are using implicit flow which is common used in JS app, if your identity server allows , you can use code flow or hybrid flow that work in web applications .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the OIDC middleware and set `SaveTokens` to true , you would subsequently be able to retrieve those tokens by calling `GetTokenAsync` for ID token you want to access ,in controller :

```
string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```